# scroll (marquee) data present in .txt file using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a txt file in which i enter data.
I want to scroll the text present inside the .txt in an html webpage.
Let me know how i can do it. I'm new to this, so please answer with the entire html code/file.
I have less idea about jquery/javascript, so please explain the working if you use them.

I want to use HTML since because all the files are in HTML, and converting it to php will be time consuming. Good answers will be appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried? SO is for helping you with your code, not to create it from scratch. I would suggest looking up ajax tutorials though. But you cannot do this with just HTML

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unlike perhaps other Q&A sites, it is not proper here to demand someone do ones entire work for them, after no attempt from the person. Break your problem into pieces, and do work to try to figure it out yourself. If you are stumped after searching for a particular problem, post that question and show you put effort into trying to answer it yourself. Only this way will you get contribution and enthusiastic response.

Comment: well, i've tried doing it myself. But didn't get the success. Refer: http://tutorialehtml.com/en/extras/marquee.php . Used this code. I can send you the project of mine. I don't know how to add HTML Code here.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this

```
<div style=" width: 99%; overflow: auto;"><marquee behavior = "scroll" direction = "up"><object type="text/html" data="filename.txt" style="width:100%; height:200px; margin:1%;"></object></marquee></div>
```

the only problem here is dt for text which is more than width of the div, the scrolling bar also becomes a part of the marquee.

Comment: This is good, but the problem is that it doesn't display the complete text (word wrap). And there is a scroll bar which is to be removed.